# What Internet connection speed do you need to watch iTunes's 4K movies?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I'm looking for ballpark figures for what 4K movies from iTunes use in terms of network bandwidth.

Is this documented or something that's a known range?

Answer (score 1):

> Apple recommends a minimum speed of 25 Mbps for 4K streaming

[Find and watch movies with 4K, HDR, or Dolby Vision - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT207949)

A nice tool to estimate what bandwidth is needed for various video formats is the Black Magic Disk Speed Test app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blackmagic-disk-speed-test/id425264550?mt=12